# Salvar dados em uma variável dentro do for em Laravel

Tags: php, array

Estou tentando salvar os dados de um loop dentro de um array, porém quando dou um `var_dump` fora do `for` ele só me mostra um dos dados alguém sabe como resolvo isto ?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Dados_sd;

class Cadastro_sp1 extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->allFiles()['arquivo']); $i++ ){
            $arquivo = array([$request->allFiles()['arquivo'][$i]->store('imagens', 'public')]);
            $path =  $arquivo;

        }
        var_dump($path);

    }
}
`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

O que está acontecendo é que você está sobrescrevendo a variável toda vez.
Para transformar em array, use os colchetes '[]'.

Olhe abaixo

```php
    path = array(); //inicializando o array (boa prática)
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

       
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->allFiles()['arquivo']); $i++ ){
            $arquivo = array([$request->allFiles()['arquivo'][$i]->store('imagens', 'public')]);
            $path[] =  $arquivo; //colocando na proxima posição livre

        }
        var_dump($path);

    }
```

Comment: Obrigado meu irmão era isto mesmo vlw.

Comment: Disponha. Bom que deu certo. Se puder aceitar a resposta, assim não fica pendente no site.